# Matlab program to see if files added yesterday have been added again

Tags: matlab

Is there an efficient way in Matlab to check if recently changed folders have been changed again recently?

e.g. In folder X a file Y was added yesterday. If today file Z was added to the same location then that is correct, if it hasn't been then produce raise error flag. And if folder A has not had files added for days/weeks then has a file B added, raise a flag also.

Comment: In which context ? On each and every Maltab's startup or just during some function of your own ?

Comment: @CitizenInsane during a function of my own, which will be set to run once a day at a set time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you know the folders you want to check in " if not you can follow the same approach to it"

so going into the folder itself

```
d=now % gets current time and date
A=dir; % get all the files inside the folder you can add masks to search for specific files
A(1:2)=[]; % remove . and ..
% now to sort files according to last modified 
S=[A(:).datenum];
[S,ix]=sort(S,'descend');
B=A(ix); % sorted files 
% now you only need to check the last couple of modified files

if d-B(1).datenum>1 % if the last modified file is older than 1 day 
flag=1;
end
if B(1).datenum-B(2).datenum > 1 % for the second case if a new file was added to a folder that hasn't been updated in a while
flag=1;
end
```